# Extreme life - energy source for living tens of kilometers underground?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, physical-chemistry, biophysics, solar-cells

Living cells were found up to at least 12 miles underground ([article](https://www.astrobio.net/extreme-life/life-might-thrive-dozen-miles-beneath-earths-surface/)), and in other extreme places ([BBC survey article](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20151124-meet-the-strange-creatures-that-live-in-solid-rock-deep-underground)), for which beside the problem of just surviving in such extreme conditions, a basic physics thermodynamical question is: **what energy source it is based on?**

And in such extreme temperatures there is needed a lot of energy just to fight 2nd law of thermodynamics - actively protect cell's structures against thermalization.

Such energy source needs to be relatively stable for past billions of years - what seems to exclude chemical energy sources (?)

One stable energy source in such high temperatures are thermal IR photons, and [thermophotovoltaics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermophotovoltaic) is generally able to harvest energy from them. However, cell living in such extreme conditions would rather have the same temperature, hence 2nd law seem to forbid harvesting energy from such IR photons?

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking about physics. What energy sources are used by *extreme life forms* is a question about biology, not physics, and probably varies with the life-form and the habitat.

Comment: +1 I have wondered this myself. The rotifers in the BBC survey survive by eating bacteria. But what do the bacteria eat? Google deep biosphere endoliths for info about microbes that live in pores inside solid rock.

Comment: This is a physics site. The questions I have are not the biological pathways. Whatever the nutrients are, how does a microbe trapped in a porous rock get them? How does it get a steady supply over a long time scale. Given that rocks form very slowly, communities that live inside stay put for very long times. This may be a geology question.

Comment: Life is a non-equilibrium thermodynamical system, which is able to maintain chemical cycles e.g. inside hot rocks underground. While biologist might not see a problem here, it seems difficult to understand from physics point of view: energy sources maintaining it out of equilibrium against 2nd law.

Comment: Why are you so sure that the chemical energy sources in the rock should be depleted after millions of years? The living organisms could have a very slow metabolism and they might also be able to slowly change location and divide in the rock.

Comment: @freecharly, if having resources, such life should replicate and exploit available resources up to depletion and starvation. It is just hard to believe that it could survive for millions of years in solid rock and temperature near water boiling point ... but maybe it is indeed true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chemical.

As the Wikipedia entry on [Lithoautotroph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithoautotroph) puts it (restricting ourselves to the deep underground forms):

> derives energy from reduced compounds of mineral origin

which they do through inorganic oxidation (see, e.g., [Lessons from the Genome of a Lithoautotroph: Making Biomass from Almost Nothing](https://dx.doi.org/10.1128%2FJB.185.9.2690-2691.2003)) or other reactions, such as the reaction of formate (HCOO-) and water, to form bicarbonate and hydrogen ([Extremophile microbes survive only on energy from formate oxidation](https://phys.org/news/2010-09-extremophile-microbes-survive-energy-formate.html)).

Comment: One article describes microbes in ocean vents where a steady supply of energy rich chemicals flows by. This makes sense. The other describes biological adaptations for living on minerals and in very nutrient poor environments. It would seem that a microbe trapped in a pore inside a rock would eat everything it could reach even with a very slow metabolism. How does it keep from running out of minerals?

Comment: @mmesser314, I can't read up on that right now, but I suppose they slowly migrate through favorable mineral veins.

Comment: I have no problem with chemical energy source for organisms living in the sea. However, as I have unsuccessfully tried to emphasize in the question, living in a rock for millions of years, chemical energy source should be depleted. The solution might be exchange through underground water streams, lava, some tectonic movement, but it still seems to require survival for thousands of years of starvation - in high temperature, requiring a lot of energy just to protect from thermalization.

Comment: What do you mean by protecting from thermalization? If they are stable at the place's temperature, they don't have to spend any energy to just stay there, have they?

Comment: Living cell requires to maintain many non-equilibria, starting with different chemical concentrations comparing with environment. Thermodynamics wants to restore equilibrium, especially in high temperatures (e.g. [Arrhenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation)) - life requires active mechanisms like ion pomps - consuming energy just to survive.

Comment: @Jarek Duda - Why are you so sure that the chemical energy sources in the rock should be depleted after millions of years? The living organisms could have a very slow metabolism and they should also be able to slowly change location in the rock.

Comment: The metabolism indeed tends to be extremely slow in energy poor conditions and, [when things get really bleak](https://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/41990/title/The-Energy-of-Life/): "When one of these cells senses nutrient stress, it draws on energy stores, activating flagella to search for food, flooding its surroundings with antibiotics to kill off competitors, or desperately importing foreign pieces of DNA in hopes that a novel capability will be the ticket out of a bad situation. If all else fails [to be continued...]"

Comment: "[...], it replicates its genetic material and partitions it into a protective capsule that can withstand extreme heat, radiation, chemical stress, desiccation, and energetically untenable conditions. Sensors located on the spore’s outer surface probe the environment for friendlier surroundings and assess the possibility of returning to a more active way of life."

Comment: @freecharly - Very slow metabolism - Yes. Some cells divide once a century or so. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endolith. Slowly change location. Good thought. Can they? I have heard doubts expressed. The pores they live in can be 10x smaller than normal bacteria cells. Some people think the same cells have been in place since the rock formed. I don't have a reference. I would like to know more.

Comment: @mmesser314, "Some people think the same cells have been in place since the rock formed" that's a cool possibility, but then how could they spread, though?

Answer (score 0):

One article to which your article points to is [this one](https://www.astrobio.net/extreme-life/life-might-thrive-dozen-miles-beneath-earths-surface/) they state:

> How would these microbes have survived? Counterintuitively, the exceedingly high pressure in a miles-deep habitat — in the neighborhood of 5,000 times the pressure exerted by the atmosphere at sea level — could have helped. High pressures actually can stabilize biomolecules, such as DNA, offsetting the heat’s destructive effects.

They also didn't stress the idea that food was unavailable...